# Azure SQL database - application user setup

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL database with sharding (single tenant approach). So, when the application connects to DB it goes into Shard and creates a proper connection to the tenant's DB (tenant is identified by login name).
However, we've been using a server admin credentials for that on a development stage. 
Now, I'd like to create a separate application user with much more limited permissions compared to server admin. 
In a very general case, what I want is to have a user that can connect to the Shard Map and figure out a connection string to any of the Shards, but have different permissions for each of the shards. For example, some application user may need to be able to connect to DB_1 with full read-write permissions, to DB_2 with read-only permissions and no permissions to connect to DB_3.

In a simpler case I just need a user that doesn't have any update permissions to ShardMap and other internal databases, but has a normal read/write/execute access to all tenant databases(shards).

I was googling around and din't find any good recipe how to do that, what are the best practices, etc. 
I'd appreciate if someone could answer me or point to a docs.
Thank yuo!

Answer (score 1):

In each database [create a role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql) for the Application Users, and grant the minimal permissions needed for the application to run.  Granting permissions on the Schema level is a good choice here, as you don't have to manage object-level permissions.

```
create role ApplicationUsers;
grant select, insert, update, delete, execute on schema::dbo to ApplicationUsers;
```

Then if you want a single identity to access all the databases, [create a login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&tabs=sqlserver) with a password.  Then in each Tenant database create a user mapped to that login.

```
--create a server-level Login
create login AppUser with Password ='asdfAds01980(*)(*)(#&$)#@';
--add a user mapped to that login in each database 
create user AppUser for login AppUser;
alter role ApplicationUsres add member AppUser;
```

Or [create a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in each database with a different password or a database user mapped to an [Azure Active Directory identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication).

```
create user AppUser with Password ='asdfAds01980(*)(*)(#&$)#@';
alter role ApplicationUsers add member AppUser;
```

or

```
create user [tenant123user@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com] from external provider;
alter role ApplicationUsers add member [tenant123user@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com];
```

Comment: Thanks @David Browne - Microsoft,
when you say "in each database", you probably mean each tenant database(shard).
I am also wondering what are the minimal required permissions needed for that login in ShardMap managing database? Does the user need any access to master database as well?

I made it working by giving db_datareader and EXECUTE permission to the AppUser in ShardMap database and also just a user in master db. However, maybe that is an overkill?